# Matrix product via trace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

Consider the matrix $A=[a_1,....,a_n]^T$ and $B=[b_1,....,b_n]^T$, where $a_j,b_j \in \mathbb{R}^p$

How can I see that I can write the following quadratic form with the trace operator:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^T M b_i = tr (AMB^T) $$

Why does equality hold here?

Comment: You literally wrote it in order to ask the question?

Comment: I want to know why this holds. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(e_i)$ be the canonical basis, so that $A^Te_i = a_i$, $B^Te_i = b_i$ and :
$$I_n = \sum_{i=1}^n e_i e_i^T$$

Therefore :
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Tr}(AMB^T) &= \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{Tr}(AMB^T e_i e_i^T) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{Tr}( e_i^TAMB^T e_i) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n  e_i^TAMB^T e_i \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n  a_i^TMb_i \\
\end{align}

Comment: How do you change the order of the $e_i$ in the second step?

Comment: Thank you for your answert:)

Comment: Cyclicity of the trace

Comment: So I can change the order inside the trace as long as the matrix multiplication does make sense?

Comment: It's a little more subtle. The property is $\operatorname{Tr}(AB) = \operatorname{Tr}(BA)$. For products of more then two matrices, you have to be careful. For example, $\operatorname{Tr}(ABC) = \operatorname{Tr}(CAB) = \operatorname{Tr}(BCA)$, but $\operatorname{Tr}(ABC)$ is not necessarily equal to $\operatorname{Tr}(ACB)$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)#Cyclic_property) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and clarifying this.